# Can MassTransit's In-Memory bus work across processes?

Tags: masstransit

I am experimenting with MassTransit's In-Memory bus, and I tried modifying the sample given by Loosely Couple Labs [Publish/Subscribe Example](http://looselycoupledlabs.com/2015/07/masstransit-3-update-a-simple-publishsubscribe-example/) to go from using RabbitMQ to the In-Memory bus. However, the subscriber doesn't seem to receive the message.

I am using version 3.1.2 of MassTransit.

In the Publisher I changed the bus creation from:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { }));
```

to:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x => { });
```

In the Subscriber I changed the bus creation from:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
    {
        var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });
        x.ReceiveEndpoint(host,
                          "MtPubSubExample_TestSubscriber",
                          e => e.Consumer<SomethingHappenedConsumer>());
    });
```

to:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x => x.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue",
                                                                 e => e.Consumer<SomethingHappenedConsumer>()));
```

When I ran this code, the messages did not get received by the subscriber console app. Since I am able to get a loopback to work within the same process, this makes me believe that the In-Memory bus won't work across processes. Is that correct, or is there a way to get the In-Memory bus to communicate between different processes on the same machine?

Comment: Have you checked the RabbitMQ web interface for what's going on? There should be a message queue create with default bindings.

Comment: I am specifically changing the `CreateUsingRabbitMq` to `CreateUsingInMemory` for the bus creation. I am trying to see how the In-Memory bus works instead of RabbitMq. As such, there is no message queue created in RabbitMq.

Comment: hmm.. I think it should work without any issue because it's an alternative for not using any persistent MQ(recommended for testing purposes only). Are you calling .Start() on the bus? See this sample for reference http://openstackwiki.org/wiki/Wie_bekomme_ich_CreateUsingInMemory()_mit_MassTransit_arbeiten%3F

Comment: I have seen that example, and successfully gotten it to work. That's an example where the publish/subscribe are in the same console app. I am trying to see if this is something that can work between two separate console apps. I am starting to suspect that the In-Memory bus only works where the publisher and subscriber are using the same bus instance, as such it looks like cross-application transport probably won't work. But, I am hoping someone has a definitive answer one way or another.

Comment: The in-memory transport is within the same process only. There is no way to use the in-memory transport to communicate between two processes.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisPatterson for the definitive answer. If you give that as an answer to the question, then I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The in-memory transport is designed for use within a single process only. It is not possible to use the in-memory transport to communicate between multiple processes (even if they are on the same machine).

It is, however, possible to share the same in-memory transport with multiple bus instances *within the same process* by configuring the transport provider. This is done in many of the unit tests, to verify behavior across bus instances.

```
return MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(x =>
{
    _inMemoryTransportCache = new InMemoryTransportCache(Environment.ProcessorCount);

    x.SetTransportProvider(_inMemoryTransportCache);

    x.ReceiveEndpoint("input_queue", configurator =>
    {
        configurator.Handler<MyMessage>(context => {});
    });
});
```

The InMemoryTransportCache can be saved and passed to multiple bus instances. Again, this is all *within the same process*.

### UPDATE

This capability was deprecated a long time ago and is not available in current version of MassTransit.